# AWS MediaLive: Unable to stream to Input Destination B

Tags: amazon-web-services, streaming

I have a standard (not single-pipeline) class channel with an RTMP push input assigned. The source of video is OBS studio on my machine. Everything goes well when I'm streaming only to the Destination A from the start. However, when I'm trying to stream only to Destination B from the beginning, nothing happens.

I believe that Destination B can be used as well, so please correct me if I'm wrong and point me to the docs about how the redundant streaming should work on MediaLive.

For the **channel** there are two output **groups**: one for HLS (both destinations are **mediastoressl**) and one for archive (both destinations with **s3ssl**)

Here is the input config:

```
{
  "inputId": "6997378",
  "inputAttachmentName": "16349",
  "inputSettings": {
    "networkInputSettings": {
      "serverValidation": "CHECK_CRYPTOGRAPHY_AND_VALIDATE_NAME"
    },
    "sourceEndBehavior": "CONTINUE",
    "inputFilter": "AUTO",
    "filterStrength": 1,
    "deblockFilter": "DISABLED",
    "denoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
    "audioSelectors": [],
    "captionSelectors": [
      {
        "selectorSettings": {
          "embeddedSourceSettings": {
            "source608ChannelNumber": 1,
            "source608TrackNumber": 1,
            "convert608To708": "DISABLED",
            "scte20Detection": "OFF"
          }
        },
        "name": "EmbeddedSelector"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here?

It details how to set up dest a and b

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/part1-how-to-send-live-video-to-aws-elemental-mediastore/